# UITabBarControllerを利用したてアクティブなタブが再度タップされたとき

Tags: swift3, uitabbarcontroller

swift3で作成しています。

UITabBarControllerを利用して画面の切り替えを行っているのですが
FirstViewControllerとSecondtViewControllerとあります。
FirstViewControllerの画面がアクティブの時、SecondtViewControllerのタブをクリックすれば
SecondtViewControllerに切り替わるのですが、
FirstViewControllerの画面がアクティブの時、FirstViewControllerのタブをクリックした場合、メッセージを出したい（printでのconsoleに表示でも可）のですが
どうしたらよいのでしょうか？

解決しました

Answer (score 0):

`UITabBarController`のサブクラスを作成し、`didSelectViewController`というデリゲートメソッドを実装すると選択されたViewControllerが取得できます。

[こちらのサイト](http://hidef.jp/post-725/)が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。  
ご紹介いただきましたサイトを参考に作成してみましたが  
上記ソースを参照し作成したのですが、  
（一部エラーになったため修正しています。）  
タブを選択しても何もコンソールに表示されません。  
  
修正した箇所はTabBarController.swiftの  
１７行目の  
v.didSelectTab(self)を  
v.didSelectTab(tabBarController: self)に  
変更しました。  
  
またFirstViewControllerの  
println(“first!”)をprint(“first!”)に  
  
何故に出力されないのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません  うまく整形されませんでした

Comment: 解決しました。  ありがとうございました